# To separate or not to separate biz & data layers in to each project in .NET

Tags: asp.net

Currently I have separate project for my business logic and a separate project for my data access. I then have various other projects for a shopping cart site, an intranet, an extranet, etc. These sites all use the biz & data projects mentioned above.

My task today was to have all these projects use a single DLL of the biz & data projects on the server. I know right now the projects are just copying the DLL locally to the project. Then I got to thinking-- I am going to be making significant changes to the Cart Site, including DB schema changes, so I will have to update the DL & BL. So if I copy up a new DLL how am I supposed to remember if it is going to break something else? I am looking at this all the wrong way? Should I have a biz logic and data access for each project separate rather than centralized?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should have a single Visual Studio Solution that has all of these projects combined underneath it, and they all reference your business and data "layer" projects. That way, if you make changes to them, breaking changes are obviated when you recompile the solution.

I've done this numerous times; I have a solution now that incorporates a Web site, a desktop client, and several shared DLLs. If I make a breaking change to the core DLLs, I'll know it.

Within the solution, the projects reference each other. That way, inter-project references are updated when I recompile.

If you're not exploiting solutions to their full advantage, you should be.

Comment: This is how I was handling it previously but I felt the solution explorer was getting a bit overcrowded. However like you said it might be worth dealing with it and having them all in one solution

Comment: Remember, too, that you can have multiple solutions.  You might have one with all the projects like mentioned, you might have one that has all of that plus test projects, you might have one that is just UI with everything else being references to compiled code.  Solutions are a good way to express different "views" to different needs.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think that way you have set your stuff up is more correct then having it all in one project. Not only does this force separation between tiers it also keeps the code more maintainable.

Good luck,
Mike

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between tiers and layers.

Answer (score 0):

> I am going to be making significant changes to the Cart Site, including DB schema changes, so I will have to update the DL & BL.

First, as recommended already, you *should* have all these projects in one solution to catch broken dependencies at compile time.  However, you can still have trouble if you alter the schema/DL to support a change and then only deploy the one project that needed to be modified.  As you noted, they will each end up with their own copy of the compiled BL/DL DLLs.  The way we handle this at my company is to always rebuild/redeploy every project in the solution *if there has been any change to the DL.*